# R - Coding Function for Bootstrap CI Coverage Property

Tags: r, simulation, simulator

I need to write a function that performs a simulation to evaluate the coverage of a bootstrap confidence interval for the variance of n samples from a normal distribution. Belowis what I've attempted but it keeps returning a mean of 0 or 0.002 for the number of samples that lie within the CI...

```
Var_CI_Coverage <- function(true_mean,true_var, nsim, nboot, alpha, nsamples){
    cover = NULL
    for(k in 1:nsim){
        Var = as.numeric()
        y <- rnorm(1, mean = true_mean, sd = sqrt(true_var))
        for(i in 1:nboot){
            resample_y <- sample(y, size = nsamples, replace = TRUE)
            Var[i] <- var(resample_y)
        }
        LB <- quantile(Var, probs=c(alpha/2))
        UB <- quantile(Var, probs=c(1 - (alpha/2)))
        cover[k] <- ifelse(LB <= true_var & UB >= true_var, 1, 0)
    }
    return(mean(cover))
}

Var_CI_Coverage(true_mean= 0, true_var = 4, nsim = 500, nboot = 1000, alpha = 0.05, nsamples = 10)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main problem is you generate `y` using

```
y <- rnorm(1, mean = true_mean, sd = sqrt(true_var))
```

which means `y` is a single value, and all your bootstrap samples are just that single `y` value repeated `nsamples` times. You need

```
y <- rnorm(nsamples, mean = true_mean, sd = sqrt(true_var))
```

Then you get samples with actual variance, and you get a coverage estimate that looks more in the right ballpark (no comment on whether it's correct, I haven't tried to check).

Comment: Omg. I'm an idiot. That makes sense. That's kind of the whole point of bootstrapping too... Thank you!